# Showing multiple twitter share buttons?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter

On a certain page in my site, a user has a list of items, like this:

```
<div id="item1">.....</div>
<div id="item2">.....</div>
<div id="item3">.....</div>
```

Each of these divs has a special link of its own on my site, like:

```
example.com/items/1
example.com/items/2
example.com/items/3
```

I want to show a twitter share button in each individual div, which when clicked, will let the user tweet the url for that particular item to their twitter.

Is there a plugin which does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for third party plugins. Go with the [Twitter plugin](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <!-- meta -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Twitter Share Buttons</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="item1"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://example.com/items/1" data-text="Text to share 1">Tweet</a></div>
    <div id="item2"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://example.com/items/2" data-text="Text to share 2">Tweet</a></div>
    <div id="item3"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://example.com/items/3" data-text="Text to share 3">Tweet</a></div>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the last `<script>` need to be put at the end of the divs or can I put it anywhere on the page?

Comment: If you like you can put it in the html head into `$(document).ready(function() { /* here goes the script */ });` if you are using jQuery. The script should be executed **after** the html tags have been interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Is there a way to do this fast for, say, 100 Twitter buttons?  My page takes ~30 seconds to load with all of the Twitter buttons.

Comment: @JohnAllen I don't know. I'd post this as a new question : ]